# Prove that a metric space is intrinsic

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Let $(X,d)$ be a general locally compact metric space (in particular not a Riemannian manifold). Suppose we don't know if $(X,d)$ is complete. To prove $(X,d)$ is *intrinsic*. I have to compute the induced intrinsic metric $\widehat{d}$, defined, for each couple of points $x,y\in X$, as the $\inf$ of the lengths with respect to $d$ of the curves from $x$ to $y$. Then I should show $d=\widehat{d}$. 
But suppose it's hard to compute $\widehat{d}$. Are there ways (or theorems) which could help me prove that $(X,d)$ is intrinsic without computing directly $\widehat{d}$?

[This  wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric)  link contains the definitions which we need in this post

Thank you!

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: consider the union of two disjoint open discs in the plane. One needs middle points, or something closer to that than you state.

Comment: It feels difficult to answer with such little information, could you tell us more about the case at hand? What kind of properties do you know or are you ready to assume on your space? What is the context?

Comment: In particular: are you assuming $(X,d)$ is a Riemannian manifold? Or are you really allowing general metric spaces?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any other property of the space, except that it's not a geodesic metric space.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko are you sure? I knew that a $complete$ metric space is intrinsic iff has middle points. But here we can't make assumptions on completeness

Comment: If the space is not complete, you could use the following version of "`intrinsic metric"': For each $\varepsilon>0$ and each pair $x$, $y$, there exists a sequence $x=x_0$, $x_1,\dots,x_N=y$ such that $d(x_{i-1},x_i)<\varepsilon$ and $\sum_{i=1}^Nd(x_{i-1},x_i)<d(x,y)+\varepsilon$. I don't know a reference for this, but I would be surprised if noone had considered this definition before. Also, with this definition, @ACL's answer might just work.

Comment: Your hypotheses are insufficient for what you call the "intrinsic metric" to make sense always. There are locally compact totally disconnected spaces bigger than a single point (e.g., the $p$-adic numbers) and in a totally disconnected space there are no paths linking two different points.

Comment: @KConrad hypermetrics (those where addition in the triangle inequality is replaced by maximum) will always become discrete when you pass to any sensible version of "intrinsic metric". On the other hand, the definition I suggested makes sense if you restrict an intrinsic metric to a dense subset (for example, by taking away a sufficiently small subset).

Answer (score 3):

Non-answer (because the argument requires completeness) : It seems that your “intrinsic metric spaces” are those metric spaces also known as *length spaces*. This theory begins with a proposition:

**Proposition.** *A *complete* metric space $(X,d)$ is a length space if and only if for every $x,y\in X$ and every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $z\in X$ such that $d(x,z), d(y,z)\leq \frac12 d(x,y)+\varepsilon$.*

The proof constructs continuous curves $c\colon[0;d(x,y)]\to X$ such that $c(0)=x$, $c(d(x,y))=y$ and $\mathop{\rm length}(c)\leq d(x,y)+\varepsilon$ by constructing points $c(s)$ such that $|t-s| d(x,y)\leq d(c(s),c(t))\leq |t-s| (d(x,y)+\varepsilon)$ for every $s$ of the form $a d(x,y)/2^n$, with $1\leq a\leq 2^n-1$, and passing to the limit.

If you know that $X$ is locally compact, then $X$ will be a *geodesic space* (Cohn–Vossen, generalization of the Hopf–Rinow theorem) : For every $x,y\in X$, there exists a geodesic linking $x$ to $y$: a continuous map $c\colon [0;d(x,y)]\to X$ such that $c(0)=x$, $c(d(x,y))=y$ and $d(c(s),c(t))=|t-s|$ for every $s,t\in[0;d(x,y)]$.

Comment: thank you, but are you sure the proposition is true without the hypothesis $(X,d)$ is complete?

Comment: I'm quite sure this doesn't work if the metric isn't complete

Comment: Of course it doesn't ! I have edited the non-answer.